# How to copy content from a excel table to another worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a table (named as Logs) in Sheet1 to which I am writing through a program. I need to copy the content written to the table Logs to Sheet2 as LogReport when I open the workbook. Is it possible to do this without using macros or Power Query option in Excel. I am working with Excel 2010. I have been searching for a while, but I was unable to find a solution which match the requirement.

Looked through the functions available as well, but I was unable to find a possible solution. Appreciate if I can get some help.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to do this without using macros?"

If under "macros" you mean VBA then the answer is **No.**

Comment: Yes I was refering to VBA

Comment: @udani - the only chance to do it w/o VBA is to do it manually.